# Enter passphrase for key 'c/users/dodie/.ssh/id_rsa':

Tags: python, git, github, ssh, openshift

I'm relatively new to openshift and python, when I made some changes to use a database with my app, I started to get this message after using the `git push` command:

```
git push
enter passphrase for key 'c/users/dodie/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I have done some research and as far as I can see you cannot retrieve passphrase, am I right in saying that?

I'm pretty sure that I left the passphrase blank, so when I enter a blank passphrase, I get the following message:

```
please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Can someone tell me what is my best option in overcoming this?

Comment: To where are you pushing? Does the repository exist? Do you have the correct access rights?

Comment: Sounds like you successfully unlocked the pass phrase, but you don't have write access to the git repository for that identity.  Upload the public key corresponding to that identity to github and give it access to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **[make a new Ssh key and add it in your service](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)**. Each time you create a ssh key you create a passphrase ( a password, if you prefer).

Normally, when you get:

```
please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

It means the service do not know you so you need to provide your ssh key to that service so you'll have enough right to `git push`. Hope it helps !

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to add your ssh key into your web service.

Comment: Any idea what te best way of doing that is??

Comment: You need to see your service's documentation on implementing a ssh key, what's your web service by the way?

Answer (score 0):

you should use this command :
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa